# Can't run function on Safari

Tags: javascript

I have this code

```
    var secondfactor = function (result) {
        console.log(window.u2f);
            window.u2f.sign(result.appId, result.challenge, [result], response => {
                console.log(response);
                axios.post("/api/v1/loginu2f", { loginResponse: response })
                .then(result => {
                    if(result.data.error) {
                        console.log(result.data)
                    } else {
                        window.location.replace("/");
                    }
                });
                //console.log(response);
            });
    }

    ...

    var ajaxlogin = null;
    $('#formlogin').on('submit', function() {
        ...
        if (!hasError) {
            //we send the form to the api
            var formdata = $('#formlogin').serializeArray();

            if (ajaxlogin && ajaxlogin.abort) ajaxlogin.abort();
            ajaxlogin= $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/api/login",
                data: formdata,
                cache: false,
                success: function (response) {
                    if (response.error) {
                        switch (response.error) {
                            case 'notfound' :
                                secondfactor(response.session)                    
                                break;
                            default:
                                $('#diverror').html('Une erreur s\'est produite, merci de réessayer ultérieurement.').show();                        
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        //on redirige sur la page désirée car l'api nous a connecté
                        location.href='/';
                    }
                },
                failure: function (response) {                    
                   console.log('response');
                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
```

On Chrome it works great but on safari the function `u2f.sign()` does not execute, I first console log show that function does exists on the u2f object :

[image]

But if I run `console.log(window.u2f.sign())` I get `undefined`, image bellow :

[image]

And here's the response object of the `.sign()` method on chrome :

[image]

I'm I doing something wrong?

Comment: what does `.sign` returns? Maybe it does not return anything?

Comment: @Justinas it does return an object on chrome

Comment: I have added the response of the `.sign()` method on chrome

Comment: @Tschallacka its Safari for iOS, Safari MacOS is just version 13, and yes I have version 13

Comment: @Tschallacka bro, please read the table correctly, Safari for MacOS support U2F since 13.0, and Safari for iOS support U2F from 13.3